# Как добавить принудительно "значение" для столбца phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Всех приветствую, а теперь сразу к вопросу.
Я совсем новичок в работе с базой данных phpMyAdmin.
Я хочу принудительно создать значение для столбца(это login и password), или же просто его добавить (не знаю, как правильно написать). Где бы я не искал - эти вопросы-ответы были чуть ли не с 2014 года, и интерфейс там совсем другой, т.е. если у кого-то было поле "значение" - то у меня его нет.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Эта фотография показывает структуру таблицы. Переключитесь на содержимое таблицы, тогда и увидите значения

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Это? https://i.imgur.com/H9apMkO.jpg

Comment: Да, это таблица значений

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Побоюсь спросить, а как добавить к примеру в login privet и в password 123456?)

Comment: [Нашёл картинку в гугле](https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/images/database/insert_tab.gif)